# What British accent do I have?

Tags: british-english, accent

What British accent do I have?

https://voca.ro/1mw6Jrr5y0yR

Comment: Do you not know, or are you trying to test other people's perceptions?

Comment: I don't recognise it from Scotland, Wales, Ireland, Northern England, Middle England, South-West England. I might imagine you to have acquired it abroad, but not Australia, Canada, probably not South Africa. So I am puzzled.

Comment: I'm not sure the accent is "regional" at all. It seems to have overtones of American and Irish, and although it's quite "fluent", i wouldn't like to bet my life the speaker is a native Anglophone. Or perhaps it's the kind of mish-mash you sometimes get from people who moved around a lot in childhood.

Comment: Where are you from? If you're a non-native speaker, try [ELL.](https://ell.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: It has hints of Midlands - Derby/Nottingham - because it has mainly northern vowels, but it's tempered by a generic 'learned' Home Counties approach to some others [many native British college students away from home for the first time develop this aspect, they all genericise each others' accents]. It could also be a northerner 'p r o n o u n c i n g everything v e r y  c a r e f u l l y'. But every so often it just goes a bit 'uncanny valley' and could be someone whose parents were in the military, so grew up 'everywhere'.

Comment: @KillingTime, I've always thought I have a slightly "vague" accent, that doesn't truly represent where I come from.

Comment: @FumbleFingers, I'm not American or Irish, although I have lived in America for the past 8 years. I spent my first 26 years in England.

Comment: @alphabet, I'm from England (I don't want to specify exactly where, so people can listen with an "open ear")

Comment: There might be elements of a Midlands / North Eastern accent (Humberside?), but I'd say it's more "rustic / rural" than metropolitan. Not really sure what the point of the question is, though.

Comment: @FumbleFingers, the point of the question is for me to find out what my accent sounds like to people, when they have no knowledge of where I'm actually from

Comment: Well, the answer is you don't have much of an accent, so if you've been living in America for 8 years, it's incredibly unlikely many of the people you converse with will have much of an opinion about it. Other than that I expect most Americans will say you sound English - but I suspect most Americans wouldn't recognize a difference even between strong Irish, Welsh, Scottish, and RP English. (If American actors putting on British accents in movies is any guide! :)

Comment: I'm sorry that you've been downvoted on your first question, but this doesn't seem to be an excellent fit for this site; it's unlikely to have lasting value for anyone else. I hope the comments were useful and interesting to you, but I think you may have to [edit] to make it more constructive. Perhaps outline a few pronunciational/lexical features of your idiolect, and ask what accents they are commonly found in. But as it stands, I think it'll be closed, because this is more of a puzzle than a genuine question.

Comment: The short 'a' in 'after', along with the tendency towards "Bookingham Palace" and "his Moother" show a regional midlands accent, but there are other influences, possibly after a uni education, and some travelling. @Tetsujin mentions the careful enunciation of some vowels, which I got too. That was before reading the comments. Is the point to focus on brushing away your roots?

Comment: @Heartspring, thanks for your feedback. I chose this StackExchange, as I couldn't find anywhere else that might be suitable online to post this kind of question (I also posted on Reddit: https://www.reddit.com/r/JudgeMyAccent/comments/182uvu5/what_british_accent_do_i_have/).
I specifically didn't want to point out anything about my accent, as I wanted listeners to hear it unbiased.

Answer (score 0):

For those wanting to know where I come from...

Manchester!

I spent my entire childhood and teenage years there, before moving out to Birmingham/Oxford/London for university/work. I later moved to America as an adult.

Based on the comments above, it looks like most people agreed I have some kind of northern/midlands accent - interesting! Not one person guessed I was from Manchester.

Comment: You've lost the "Ey, are kid" aspect that would have distinguished you as a Manc;)[I'm from Leeds, btw, so I can easily tell the difference the Pennines makes] All I can hear that's left is the 'generic northern 'a' - which has also been softened from Manchester down as far as even Leicester [or any of those Midland towns north of Danelaw. The rest has been subsumed by Oxford/London. I'll claim I did get that, the 'uni' accent everybody absorbs a bit of [though I don't hear a single hint of Brum.] Once you're past 20 or so any further accent change would have to be a conscious decision.